# Calculate interval in timestamps by groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table with My Id, "rank" the order messages where sent, and the message_send_time.

```
ID      Rank          message_send_time      
1         1          2022-01-01 00:33:04              
1         2          2022-01-01 00:34:04            
2         1          2022-01-01 00:30:04        
2         2          2022-01-01 00:32:04            
2         3          2022-01-01 00:33:04
```

I want to calculate the interval of minutes between my group Id and based on the rank oh the messages, how I can calculate this in SQL ?

```
ID      Rank          message_send_time       Interval_time_minutes
1         1          2022-01-01 00:33:04              
1         2          2022-01-01 00:34:04            1
2         1          2022-01-01 00:30:04        
2         2          2022-01-01 00:32:04            2
2         3          2022-01-01 00:33:04            1
```

Comment: which rdms are you using? everyone gas its own functions

Comment: At least, does your DBMS support OLAP functions, also called analytic or "window" functions, especially the `LAG(..) OVER(...)` function?

Comment: @marcothesane yes does support LAG

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `lag` window function with `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

**Query #1**

```
select
  id, 
  `Rank`,
  message_send_time,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,lag(message_send_time,1) over (partition by id order by `Rank`),message_send_time) Interval_time_minutes
from T;
```

| id | Rank | message_send_time | Interval_time_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 00:33:04 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-01 00:34:04 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01 00:30:04 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-01-01 00:32:04 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-01-01 00:33:04 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wCoMBKPyW3gvUk2tpmwcGY/4)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the functions `datediff()` and `lag()`

> ```
> create table messages(
> ID int,
> message_send_time timestamp);
> insert into messages values
> (1,' 2022-01-01 00:33:04'),
> (1,' 2022-01-01 00:34:04'),
> (2,' 2022-01-01 00:30:04'),
> (2,' 2022-01-01 00:32:04'), 
> (2,' 2022-01-01 00:33:04');
> ```

> ```
> select
>   id, 
>   rank() over(partition by id order by message_send_time) "Rank",
>   message_send_time,
>   timediff(
>     message_send_time,
>     lag(message_send_time,1) over (partition by id order by message_send_time) 
>      ) as "Interval"
> from messages;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | Rank | message_send_time   | Interval
> -: | ---: | :------------------ | :-------
>  1 |    1 | 2022-01-01 00:33:04 | null    
>  1 |    2 | 2022-01-01 00:34:04 | 00:01:00
>  2 |    1 | 2022-01-01 00:30:04 | null    
>  2 |    2 | 2022-01-01 00:32:04 | 00:02:00
>  2 |    3 | 2022-01-01 00:33:04 | 00:01:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=028df9b18d604ad2f801833918504d56)*

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  id 
, `Rank`
, message_send_time,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(
     MINUTE
   , LAG(message_send_time,1) over (
       partition by id order by `Rank`
     )
   , message_send_time
   ) Interval_time_minutes
from T;
```